# Limit Requests to an External API in Laravel Using Job and Queue

Tags: laravel, queue, limit, jobs

I am using Laravel 6 and I have an external API. I want to limit the requests to this API to one request per 10 seconds.This API is called inside a job. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Laravel 6 you can [delay](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queues#delayed-dispatching) the job. So you do like:

`JobClass::dispatch($payload)->delay(now()->addSeconds(10));`

You may throttle a given type of job to only run 1 time every 10 seconds. So to impose this [`throttle`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queues#rate-limiting) it requires redis and you do like:

`Redis::throttle('key')->allow(1)->every(10)->then(function () {`

You can set time to the [failed jobs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queues#dealing-with-failed-jobs) so it takes time.

```
/**
 * The number of seconds to wait before retrying the job.
 *
 * @var int
 */
public $retryAfter = 10;
```